# How do I get mixed fractions, negative fractions, and reduced fractions working in my fraction calculator?

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator

I'm trying to create a fraction calculator in Java that takes whole numbers, mixed fractions, improper fractions, and negative fractions. The only thing that I can get working right now is multiplying, adding, subtracting, and dividing simple fractions. I need to be able to reduce them. Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class Project2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an expression or quit"); //asks user
    String num1 = input.next();
    String operation = input.next();
    String num2 = input.next();

    String nume1 = num1.substring(0,1); //first numerator
    int newNume1 = Integer.parseInt(nume1);  //convert to int
    String deno1 = num1.substring(2,3);  //first denominator
    int newDeno1 = Integer.parseInt(deno1);  //convert to int

    String nume2 = num2.substring(0,1);  //second numerator
    int newNume2 = Integer.parseInt(nume2);  //convert to int
    String deno2 = num2.substring(2,3);  //second denominator
    int newDeno2 = Integer.parseInt(deno2);  //convert to int


    if(num1.equals("quit")){
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
    else{
        //prints fraction
        System.out.println("Fraction 1: " + num1);
        System.out.println("Operation: " + operation);
        System.out.println("Fraction 2: " + num2);
        System.out.println("Numerator 1: " + newNume1);
        System.out.println("Denominator 1: " + newDeno1);
        System.out.println("Numerator 2: " + newNume2);
        System.out.println("Denominator 2: " + newDeno2);
    }

    if(operation.equals("+")){
        //adds numerators if denominators are the same
        if(newDeno1 == newDeno2){
            System.out.println("Answer is " + (newNume1 + newNume2) + "/" + + newDeno2);
        }
        else{
            int newDenom = newDeno1 * newDeno2;
            int multiplyNume = newNume1 * newDeno2;
            int multiplyNume2 = newNume2 * newDeno1;
            int finalNume = multiplyNume + multiplyNume2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + finalNume + "/" + newDenom);
        }

    }

    if(operation.equals("-")){
        //subtracts numerators if denominators are the same
        if(newDeno1 == newDeno2){
            System.out.println("Answer is " + (newNume1 - newNume2) + "/" + + newDeno2);
        }
        else{
            int newDenom = newDeno1 * newDeno2;
            int multiplyNume = newNume1 * newDeno2;
            int multiplyNume2 = newNume2 * newDeno1;
            int finalNume = multiplyNume - multiplyNume2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + finalNume + "/" + newDenom);
        }
    }

    if(operation.equals("*")){
        //multiplies numerators and denominators
        System.out.println("Answer is: " + newNume1 *  newNume2 + "/" + newDeno1 * newDeno2);

    }

    if(operation.equals("/")){
        System.out.println("Answer is: " + newNume1 *  newDeno2 + "/" + newDeno1 * newNume2);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried? Just off the top of my head, a function that would check the GCD of your numerators and denominators and return the fraction if mod = 0 would probably accomplish this.

Comment: Program hangs when input "1/2+3/2" is entered.

Comment: Where exactly does it hang? Do you get any output? Your should at least see some of your print statements executed.

Comment: You have all of your code in one main method.  Write smaller methods that do one thing, like reduce a fraction, convert an improper fraction to a proper fraction, and so on.  Smaller methods are easier to test.